# Integral of absolute values

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, integration, vector-fields

Work done is given by the integral
$$\int \vec F\cdot d\vec r$$
Where $\vec F$ is force and $d\vec r$ is displacement. Writing displacement in terms of velocity, we get
$$\int\vec F\cdot\vec v\,dt=\int m\frac{d \vec v}{dt}\cdot\vec v\, dt$$
This then reduces to
$$\int \vec F\cdot d\vec r=\frac12m(v^2-u^2)\tag1$$
Here, v and u are final and initial speeds, respectively, and not velocities.

But now consider the integral
$$\int\vert\vec F\vert \vert d\vec r\vert$$
Writing this in terms of speed, we get
$$\int\vert\vec F\vert \vert d\vec r\vert=\int m\vert\vec a\vert v\, dt \\
=\int m \frac{dv}{dt}v\,dt$$

Now, this seems to give the same result as equation 1 as follows:

$$ \int\vert\vec F\vert \vert d\vec r\vert=\int m vdv $$
$$                                             =\frac12m(v^2-u^2) \tag2 $$
Since the integrand vdv is a simple 1D integral, where v is the speed. Thus equation 1 and 2 seem to be equal.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: "What did I do wrong?" I'd say this falls off-topic as a check-my-work: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic

Comment: In my opinion, these kind of check-my-work questions are easier to call "off-topic" where there are clear and obvious errors. These kinds of questions and answers are not helpful to anyone (except maybe OP).

Comment: I think this is at heart a conceptual question about a subtle point that confuses a lot of beginning physics students. Personally I wouldn't close it. Maybe the title could be more descriptive to help people search for it? "Why is the magnitude of acceleration different from the rate of change of speed?"

Comment: @Andrew I think in that case posting a clear conceptual question (or significantly editing the question to make the issue clear) would make more sense.

Comment: Editing the question to clarify the issue for other users at this point may make sense. But maybe it's also not surprising that sometimes the underlying conceptual issue isn't clear to a student at the point when they ask a question.

Comment: @Andrew From the point of view of the asker, yes. But from the point of view of your argument, that this is a more general question (which would justify not closing it), it would be important to have it phrased in a way where others would recognize that this is also their issue.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I tried to do that but wasn't sure how to. The main issue is that there is a relation between acceleration, displacement, and force which makes the question arise at first place. Thus any generality that I can think of will be to change the names of these physical quantities and call them variables a, b, and c, respectively for example. The best that I can do is to change the title as suggested by Andrew.

Comment: @hft I think my *Now, this seems to give the same result as equation 1 as follows:* checks out with the 4th point of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magnitude of acceleration $|\vec{a}|$ is not the same thing as the rate of change of the speed $\frac{dv}{dt}$. First, note that $|\vec{a}|\geq 0$ while $\frac{dv}{dt}$ can be positive, negative, or zero (even though $v\geq 0$). Second, for uniform circular motion of radius $r$, $|\vec{a}|=\frac{v^2}{r}$ while $\frac{dv}{dt}=0$.

To be more careful, writing $\vec{v} = v \hat{e}_v$ (where $\hat{e}_v$ is a unit vector in the direction of the velocity),
\begin{eqnarray}
|\vec{a}| &=& \sqrt{ \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} \cdot \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} } \\
&=& \sqrt{ \left(\frac{dv}{dt}\right)^2 + v^2 \frac{d \hat{e}_v}{dt} \cdot \frac{d \hat{e}_v}{dt} }
\end{eqnarray}
Note that $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\hat{e}_v \cdot \hat{e}_v\right) = \frac{d}{dt}(1) = 0$, which implies $\hat{e}_v \cdot \frac{d \hat{e}_v}{dt} = 0$, which is a fact we used above.

Answer (score 2):

$|\vec a|$ is $|d\vec v/dt|$, not $dv/dt = d|\vec v|/dt$.

For instance, in circular motion, $|d\vec v/dt|$ is non-zero, while $dv/dt$ is zero.